# Aquamacs automatic line break configuration

Tags: macos, aquamacs

When editing a text file with Aquamacs, if I type a long line it likes to automatically break the line (insert a newline) after ~70 characters. How do I turn this "feature" off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably with called "auto-wrap" or "soft-wrap". Check menu's and preferences because I'm not familiar with the program, but that behavior is text wrapping.

Comment: Thanks, that was the hint I needed. The trick is to turn on "Soft Word Wrap" from the Options menu. (I had been mucking around in preferences and finding nothing)